# Rails Foundation Reveal Modal Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, zurb-foundation

I am trying to get a Foundation 5 reveal modal on my webpage.

Heres what I have:

Gemfile:

```
gem 'foundation-rails', '~> 6.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'query-ui-rails'
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require autocomplete-rails
//= require foundation
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .

$(function(){ 
    $(document).foundation(); 
});
```

show.html.erb

```
<a href="#" data-reveal-id="myModal" class=" small button">Click Me For A Modal</a>

<div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal aria-labelledby="modalTitle" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog">
  <h2 id="modalTitle">Awesome. I have it.</h2>
  <p class="lead">Your couch.  It is mine.</p>
  <p>I'm a cool paragraph that lives inside of an even cooler modal. Wins!</p>
  <a class="close-reveal-modal" aria-label="Close">&#215;</a>
</div>
```

I was following the instructions here: http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/reveal.html

I want it to appear and work exactly how their Basic example does, but it is not working properly.

Right now I can display the modal button, and when you click it, the page refreshes and then the contents of the modal are displayed, and I am unable to close it. It just stays open until I refresh the page.

Renders like this:
[image]

I do not understand what I am missing. From everything I have read, since I have foundation installed in my app, I should have all the necessary components to make this work properly.

Further down the page they mention:

> Before you can use Reveal you'll want to verify that jQuery and
>   foundation.min.js are available on your page. You can refer to the
>   Javascript documentation on setting that up.

I do not understand anything about this `foundation.min.js`. I downloaded the full Foundation library and tried adding that file to my `app/assets/javascripts/foundation.min.js` and then added `<script src="/js/foundation.min.js"></script>` to my `application.html.erb` in the `<head>` but that also made no difference.

At this point I have no idea what I am missing. They modal isn't working and the Foundation styling for the modal isn't even being applied. Can someone please help me along?